# だからって and ってだけで difference

Tags: word-choice, usage

I come across だからって and ってだけで quite often and I understand both of them as "only because", but I can't grasp the difference in nuance between the two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ってだけで -- colloquial/collapsed way of saying と言うだけで
(だ)からって -- colloquial/collapsed way of saying (だ)からと言って

These can often be translated the same way ("only because..."), but they are not always interchangeable. For example...

> 〇 美人(だ)｛**ってだけで** / というだけで｝人気がある。
>   × 美人だ｛からって / からといって｝人気がある。
>   (Someone) is popular only because she's pretty.

> 〇 美人だ｛**からって** / からといって｝、人気があるとは限らない。
>   ? 美人(だ)｛ってだけで / というだけで｝、人気があるとは限らない。
>   (Someone) is pretty doesn't always mean she is popular.

～からって / ～からと言って meaning "only because~~" is usually followed by a phrase with a negative meaning, as in the common expressions 「～だからって、～とは限ら**ない**」, 「～からといって、～ということにはなら**ない**」 (so 「美人だからといって人気がある。」 sounds strange).

Answer (score 2):

Aだからって

Because someone/something is A

子供だからって相手にされなかった
(The condition in this sentence is "because you are a child", but it's not necessarily a sufficient condition)

AてだけでB

Only because of A

子供ってだけで相手にされなかった
(The condition of "being a child" is sufficient)

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe say ってだけで is more akin to "only due to (A) happening, did (B) happen."

Where as だからって is more like "because of (A), (B) happened."

They basically sort of express the same thing but in a differently nuanced way.