# What does からって mean?

Tags: particle-から, particle-って

Sentence is: 世界に出たからってファイナルまで残んなきゃ稼げねーし
I mostly understand the meaning "We can't make money unless we make it to the finals in the world championships" but what does the からって do here?

Comment: You sure it wasn’t 空手?

Comment: ^ Nah.. What would 世界に出た空手ファイナルまで残んなきゃ稼げねえ mean??

Answer (score 7):

> 世界に出たからってファイナルまで残んなきゃ稼げねーし
>   Just because I entered the world doesn't mean I can earn money without making it to the finals.

- から: because
- って = といって = "even though", "however" in this case. 明鏡 defines this as:

  > #### といって
  >
  > 連語〔接続詞的に〕前の事柄を認めたうえで、それに反する事柄が成り立つ意を表す。…だけれども、しかし。…だとしても。「気持ちはわかる。━認めるわけにはいかない」

In general, you can learn `X(だ)からといってYない` as a pattern that means "Just because X doesn't mean Y".

Related:

- [だからって and ってだけで difference](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47301/5010)